# Raster satellite images for QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, imagery, satellite

When I try to apply a downloaded GIS satellite (t=rimage to Quantum, it doesn't seem to open properly.  There must be a step-by step description on how this would be done effectively.  Can anyone tell me where to find it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you provide more details? What satellite images are you working with?  What file formats are you using?

Comment: Also if you can't explain what is  the problem you could add a screenshot of your raster in question.

Comment: Oh!  You folks are there!!!  I checked this shortly after I posted and nothing...And you all checked things in early December.  I will get an image out to you this week if I can and we can figure this out--I have been killing myself over it!

Comment: Hey, I finally got it!!!  Some raster layers from a friend (Katie Callaghan, GIS Specialist at NH Fish&Game no less) opened right up in a "New Project".  I will add some shapefiles with my own GPS points as soon as I can to keep you posted maybe I can show off posting an image on this forum.  Still no satellite images though, I will try that that too.